# place two iframes side by side

Tags: iframe, html

I want to create two iframes and place them side by side. Previously I had placed two divs side by side, but when I replace them by iframe only my first iframe get loaded and another can't be seen. How to place them in single page?

the code which i used

```
<div class="column4" id="lb">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="90" valign="top">
                <div style="text-align:left;height:260px;background-color:#f3f5f6;width:110%;">
            </td>
            <td width="80"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div>
                    <div style="padding-top:7px;padding-left:0px;text-align:center;background-color:#385870;width:695px;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;height:16px;">heading</div>
                    <div class="cs1">
                        <iframe class="cs1" src="page1.php" name="frame2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="80"></td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div>
                    <div style="padding-top:7px;padding-left:0px;text-align:center;background-color:#385870;width:695px;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;height:16px;">heading</div>
                    <div class="cs1">
                        <iframe class="cs1" src="page2.php" name="frame1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to avoid using iframe

Comment: then two load two differnt page in single page what can we use

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe class="cs1" src="page1.php" name="frame2" />
                                                 ***
```

I’m pretty sure your problem lies right here: The browser does not recognize a self-closing iframe tag, and so he treats everything that follows as the “fallback-content” to be displayed when iframes are not supported.

Write your iframe elements in the form

```
<iframe class="cs1" src="page1.php" name="frame2"></iframe>
```

then it should work.